# connecting to phpMyAdmin app on WD EX4 through DNS

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have the phpMyAdmin app on my WD EX4 and for a while, I had my EX4 set up as the DMZ point on my router. I could connect to the databases through my DNS name with the /phpMyAdmin at the end with no problem. I could then go in and do anything I wanted remotely as I could locally. With some changes I have been making on my home network, I no longer want the EX4 to be a DMZ point. Any DNS name I create goes to the EX4 rather then the device I want it to go so I had to shut that off. With my DNS address, I can get to the log in screen of the phpMyAdmin app but after logging in, I get the error that the page cant connect. That seems odd since I can at least get to log in. I did go in and made sure the host name on both user and the host name in the host table are correct. Still the same thing. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by looking through the log files -- does your webserver log anything after you press submit? Where is it redirecting you? Check whether your browser is using https or http and verify that it's still using the same method when it can't connect.